# Load URL from text box into iframe

Tags: javascript, html, url, input

How do you load a URL from a text box into iframe in a HTML file via javascript?

Answer (score 7):

```
var oIFrame = document.getElementById("id_of_iframe");
oIFrame.src = document.getElementById("id_of_textbox").value;
```

Comment: I would modify that to add error checking at each step: `if (oIFrame != null)...`

Answer (score 0):

Or with document.frames if its the only iframe you are using:

```
var myIframe = window.document.frames[0]; // lets grab the iframe object
if (myIframe != null){
  myIframe.src = document.getElementById("id_of_textbox").value; // set the value as source.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add I guess, via jQuery

```
$('iframe#guid').src( $('#textbox_id').val() );
```

with error checking:

```
var iframe = $('#guid');
if(iframe.length > 0){
    iframe.attr('src', $('#textbox_id').val());
}
```